# How can I add multiple tables to dataset with Fill using IDataAdapter?

Tags: c#, ado.net, dataset, dataadapter

Refering to [How can I read multiple tables into a dataset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170455/how-can-i-read-multiple-tables-into-a-dataset#answer-366402)
My App has a db factory. Can i use 'da.Fill(ds)' [with IDataAdapter implementation] for multiple tables? Or how can i add more tables to the same DataSet. Copy the whole table would work but is this the only way?

Rolf

Answer (score 0):

da.Fill(ds.Tables.Add())

Hope it may helps